# How set watermark in word file using Aspose.Word for Java

Tags: java, ms-word, aspose.words

Here is my code. But its not working.

```
private static void insertWatermarkText(Document doc, String watermarkText) throws Exception
    {
        // Create a watermark shape. This will be a WordArt shape.
        // You are free to try other shape types as watermarks.
        Shape watermark = new Shape(doc, ShapeType.TEXT_PLAIN_TEXT);

    // Set up the text of the watermark.
    watermark.getTextPath().setText(watermarkText);
    watermark.getTextPath().setFontFamily("Arial");
    watermark.setWidth(500);
    watermark.setHeight(100);
    // Text will be directed from the bottom-left to the top-right corner.
    watermark.setRotation(-40);
    // Remove the following two lines if you need a solid black text.
    watermark.getFill().setColor(Color.GRAY); // Try LightGray to get more Word-style watermark
    watermark.setStrokeColor(Color.GRAY); // Try LightGray to get more Word-style watermark

    // Place the watermark in the page center.
    watermark.setRelativeHorizontalPosition(RelativeHorizontalPosition.PAGE);
    watermark.setRelativeVerticalPosition(RelativeVerticalPosition.PAGE);
    watermark.setWrapType(WrapType.NONE);
    watermark.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    watermark.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

    // Create a new paragraph and append the watermark to this paragraph.
    Paragraph watermarkPara = new Paragraph(doc);
    watermarkPara.appendChild(watermark);

    // Insert the watermark into all headers of each document section.
    for (Section sect : doc.getSections())
    {
        // There could be up to three different headers in each section, since we want
        // the watermark to appear on all pages, insert into all headers.
        insertWatermarkIntoHeader(watermarkPara, sect, HeaderFooterType.HEADER_PRIMARY);
        insertWatermarkIntoHeader(watermarkPara, sect, HeaderFooterType.HEADER_FIRST);
        insertWatermarkIntoHeader(watermarkPara, sect, HeaderFooterType.HEADER_EVEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Not working" is way to vague.  Please tell us exactly what isn't working, what errors do you get, what do you actually get vs what you expected, and so on.

Comment: I think, I'm using old jar files.

Comment: You still haven't said what is going wrong....

Comment: @fvu: Could you please suggest me any Java Api for this??

Comment: [Apache PO HWPF+XWPF](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) is the best known API to work with Word documents, but I'm not sure it will be able to do what you want to do here... [OpenOffice UNO](http://www.openoffice.org/udk/) is another option, but it's far from trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @fvu. I go through with the [Apache PO API](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) but i didn't any way to set watermark.

Comment: For what it is worth, a link to how to do it with docx4j:- https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/Watermark.java

Comment: @JasonPlutext: Its working. But why we are using openxml??

Comment: @JasonPlutext: can we replace a text from .doc file using docx4j.

Comment: docx4j is for docx files, not legacy binary doc files.  If you want to work with those, you need to convert them to docx first, using say JODConverter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue. Actually it was conflict of jar file.
[Here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://www.aspose.com/community/files/72/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/entry456393.aspx) I got the new jar files. Now my code is working.
**Here is the updated code :**

```
/**
 * Inserts a watermark into a document.
 *
 * @param doc The input document file.
 * @param watermarkText Text of the watermark.
 */
private static void insertWatermarkText(Document doc, String watermarkText) throws Exception
{
    // Create a watermark shape. This will be a WordArt shape.
    // You are free to try other shape types as watermarks.
    Shape watermark = new Shape(doc, ShapeType.TEXT_PLAIN_TEXT);

    // Set up the text of the watermark.
    watermark.getTextPath().setText(watermarkText);
    watermark.getTextPath().setFontFamily("Arial");
    watermark.setWidth(500);
    watermark.setHeight(100);
    // Text will be directed from the bottom-left to the top-right corner.
    watermark.setRotation(-40);
    // Remove the following two lines if you need a solid black text.
    watermark.getFill().setColor(Color.GRAY); // Try LightGray to get more Word-style watermark
    watermark.setStrokeColor(Color.GRAY); // Try LightGray to get more Word-style watermark

    // Place the watermark in the page center.
    watermark.setRelativeHorizontalPosition(RelativeHorizontalPosition.PAGE);
    watermark.setRelativeVerticalPosition(RelativeVerticalPosition.PAGE);
    watermark.setWrapType(WrapType.NONE);
    watermark.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    watermark.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

    // Create a new paragraph and append the watermark to this paragraph.
    Paragraph watermarkPara = new Paragraph(doc);
    watermarkPara.appendChild(watermark);

    // Insert the watermark into all headers of each document section.
    for (Section sect : doc.getSections())
    {
        // There could be up to three different headers in each section, since we want
        // the watermark to appear on all pages, insert into all headers.
        insertWatermarkIntoHeader(watermarkPara, sect, HeaderFooterType.HEADER_PRIMARY);
        insertWatermarkIntoHeader(watermarkPara, sect, HeaderFooterType.HEADER_FIRST);
        insertWatermarkIntoHeader(watermarkPara, sect, HeaderFooterType.HEADER_EVEN);
    }
    System.out.println("Watermark Set");
}

private static void insertWatermarkIntoHeader(Paragraph watermarkPara, Section sect, int headerType) throws Exception
{
    HeaderFooter header = sect.getHeadersFooters().getByHeaderFooterType(headerType);

    if (header == null)
    {
        // There is no header of the specified type in the current section, create it.
        header = new HeaderFooter(sect.getDocument(), headerType);
        sect.getHeadersFooters().add(header);
    }

    // Insert a clone of the watermark into the header.
    header.appendChild(watermarkPara.deepClone(true));
}
```